# Can only print a char, and not a string

Tags: c, arrays

I'm getting really confused about arrays and printing out strings.
I have a slight problem in my program where it doesn't print out a string, and only the character.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main() {

    char myarray[] = { 'A', 'A', 'BE', 'CE' };  
    srand(time(NULL));
    char number;
    number = myarray[rand() % 4];

    if (number == 'A') {
        printf("%c", number);
    }
    else {
        printf("%s", number);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

So when the program runs, it works fine if the random number is equal to A, then it prints out A. However, when the number != to A, it crashes and doesn't print out BE or CE. Why is that? I have used `%s`, but I can't actually see my problem.

Comment: Turn on your compiler warnings. Turn your compiler to strict standards compliance. Then follow the information that's printed by the compiler.

Comment: Characters (`char`)  and strings (`char*` or array of `char`) are different types and can't be mixed together in the same array. And a string should be specified as `"BE"` and not `'BE'`.

Answer (score 1):

The statement `printf("%s", number);` causes undefined behaviour at runtime, since `%s` requires that the corresponding argument is a pointer to `char`, but you are not providing a pointer to a `char`.

(Any decent compiler, sensibly operated, will tell you about such mismatched printf arguments.)

Here is probably what you mean:

```
const char * a[] = { "A", "A", "BE", "BC" };

printf("%s", a[rand() % 4]);
```

Comment: So, how will this look with a pointer? how will the correct code look like?

Comment: @Philly: I added that.

Answer (score 1):

The crash is mostly due to this line:

```
    printf("%s", number);
```

where you use incorrect format specifier. `%s` is for printing c-string. But `number` is of `char`.

Even then, it might not produce the output you would expect because `BE` and `CE` are multi-byte character constants, which has implementation-defined behaviour.

Instead, you could use an array of pointers:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#include <time.h>

int main() {

    char *myarray[] = { "A", "A", "BE", "CE" };  
    srand(time(NULL));
    char *number;
    number = myarray[rand() % 4];

    if (strcmp(number, "A") == 0) {
        printf("%s", number);
    }
    else {
        printf("%s", number);
    }
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help!
But cant i just use if ( number == 'A') to avoid using the library string.h?

Comment: No. You must use `strcmp()` for comparing C-strings (a sequence of bytes with a terminating NUL byte). If it's single char such as `'A'` then then `==` is fine.

Comment: Okay, and whats the reason for why we use "A" and not 'A'? Whats the difference? And why does the program break when using 'A' and not "A"

Comment: `'A'` is a single character. `"A"` is string literal which is an array of 2 characters -- one is `'A'` and other is the terminating NUL byte.

Answer (score 1):

You used the wrong format specifier for `printf`. A modern compiler will give a warning for this. `%c` must be used for a `char`, not `%s`.

The behaviour of the character constants `'BE'` and `'CE'`, when assigned to a `char`, is *implementation-defined*.  They might get truncated to `'E'`, or something else.

There are no strings in your code. String literals are introduced by double-quotes.